# pgAdmin access control to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am interested in barring pgAdmin access to my PostgreSQL server from any station other than the server. Is is possible to do this using pg_hba.conf? The PostgreSQL server should still allow access to the server for my application from other stations.

Comment: You can't block access based on the SQL client application being used.

Comment: you can block access from any station other than the server with hba_file though, no matter the client

Comment: Maybe better suited on [dba.se]

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. Nor is it sensible, since the client (mode of access) isn't the issue, but what you do on the connection.

If the user managed to trick your app into running arbitrary SQL via SQL injection or whatever, you'd be back in the same position.

Instead, set your application up to use a restricted user role that:

- is not a superuser
- does not own the tables it uses
- has only the minimum permissions `GRANT`ed to it that it needs

and preferably also add guards such as triggers to preserve data consistency within the DB. This will help mitigate the damage that can be done if someone extracts database credentials from the app and uses them directly via a SQL client.

You can also make it harder for someone with your app's binary etc to extract the credentials and use them to connect to postgres directly by:

- using `md5` authentication
- if you use a single db role shared between all users, either (a) don't do that or (b) store a well-obfuscated copy of the db password somewhere non-obvious in the configuration, preferably encrypted against the user's local credentials
- using `sslmode=verify-full` and a server certificate
- embedding a client certificate in your app and requiring that it be presented in order for the connection to be permitted by the server (see [client certificates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html)

Really, though, if you can't trust your uses not to be actively malicious and run `DELETE FROM customer;` etc ... you'll need middleware to guard the SQL connection and apply further limits. Rate-limit access, disallow bulk updates, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.